# Running mp3 Format file

Tags: c#

I have this code in c#. But it does not run mp3 format file. Could you tell me what the error is in this code snippet:

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();             
wplayer.URL = "D://j.mp3";             
wplayer.Controls.Play();
```

Comment: You could start by telling us what your error is?

Comment: *"Tell me what is error in this code"* - that's your job, not ours...

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'WMPLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `"D://j.mp3"` is probably not what you are looking for. I guess you probably mean `"D:/j.mp3"` or `"D:\\j.mp3"`, both of which should work.

Comment: Did you read the message? Did you even try to [search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564585(v=vs.85).aspx) for WMPLib?

Comment: i can,t understand which one is correct ?  // or / ?

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search on your class name yeilds:

> "To create the Windows Media Player control programmatically, you
>   must first add a reference to wmp.dll, which is found in the
>   \Windows\system32 folder. Adding this reference creates WMPLib.dll in
>   your project folder, and a reference to WMPLib appears in Solution
>   Explorer."

sourced from: [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).